# Redux toolkit infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm new in Redux and I've got some issues learning it.

If I call a selector before a dispatch it becomes in an infinite loop, but if I call the selector after the dispatch action it works fine. I've followed documentations steps and look through stack-overflow and couldn't find some issue similar.

I let the code below:

1. selector:

```
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from '@/store';

export const selectCount = (state: RootState) => state.learningLanguages;

export const countSelector = createSelector(selectCount, state => state);
```

2. action:

```
import {createAction} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import {LearningLanguagesType} from "@/globals";

export const storeLearningLanguages = createAction<LearningLanguagesType[]>('languages/store')
```

3. reducer

```
import {
    createReducer, createSlice, PayloadAction,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { LearningLanguagesType } from "@/globals";
import {storeLearningLanguages} from "@/store";


const initialState: LearningLanguagesType[] = [{
    id: 'en',
    name: 'english',
    level: '0'
}];

export const learningLanguagesReducer = createReducer(initialState, builder => {
    builder
        .addCase(storeLearningLanguages, (state, action) => {
            return action.payload;
        });
});
```

4. hooks

```
import {
    TypedUseSelectorHook,
    useDispatch,
    useSelector,
} from 'react-redux';
import type {
    AppDispatch,
    RootState,
} from '.';

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

5. store

```
import {
    Action,
    configureStore,
    ThunkAction,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {learningLanguagesReducer} from './app/languages/reducer'
export const index = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        learningLanguages : learningLanguagesReducer
    },
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof index.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof index.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
    ReturnType,
    RootState,
    unknown,
    Action<string>
    >;
```

6. execution

```
import {
    useAppDispatch,
    useAppSelector,
} from '@/store/hooks'
import {LearningLanguagesType} from "@/globals";

const Home =  () => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const testLang: LearningLanguagesType[] = [
        {
            id: 'es',
            name: 'Spain',
            level: '0'
        },
        {
            id: 'en',
            name: 'English',
            level: '0'
        }
    ];

    console.log('before',useAppSelector(countSelector))
    console.log('dispatch', (dispatch(storeLearningLanguages(testLang))))
    console.log('after',useAppSelector(countSelector))

 }
```

This way works perfectly, and it doesn't matter how many times I call the selector after the dispatch:

```
    //console.log('before',useAppSelector(countSelector))
    console.log('dispatch', (dispatch(storeLearningLanguages(testLang))))
    console.log('after',useAppSelector(countSelector))
```

Thanks anyway.